# How to count number of records in a section in ms-access report?

Tags: vba, ms-access

On my report I have sections that are summarized at the bottom. Some of the sections have only one record though. In that case, I don't want to show the Total. So, basically, I am looking for something like my code below (which doesn't work because RecordCount is not Sections property). Any solutions?

```
Private Sub prv_subtotal_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)

If Me.Section("prv_subtotal").RecordCount = 1 Then Cancel = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a hidden textbox in the detail section and set the controlsource to =1 and RunningSum to OverGroup.
Then change your code to 
Cancel = (me!hiddentextbox = 1)

Comment: I was aware of this work-around solution but was hoping a better way existed. But anyways, thanks.

Comment: Why would you consider it a workaround? It is a valid and common solution.